# How to access array member in PHP

Tags: php

I just like to know how take only the browser name using this code.

```
<?php
echo $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'] . "\n\n";

$browser = get_browser(null, true);
print_r($browser);
?>
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Chris Schuld has a nice [PHP browser detection script.](http://chrisschuld.com/projects/browser-php-detecting-a-users-browser-from-php/)

Comment: Accessing array member ?? :P deceiving

Comment: He has his name, he just don't know how to access it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$browser['browser']`

your code will output:

```
`Array
        (
            [browser_name_regex] => ^mozilla/5\.0 (windows; .; windows nt 5\.1; .*rv:.*) gecko/.* firefox/0\.9.*$
            [browser_name_pattern] => Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; ?; Windows NT 5.1; *rv:*) Gecko/* Firefox/0.9*
            [parent] => Firefox 0.9
            [platform] => WinXP
            [browser] => Firefox 
            [version] => 0.9
            [majorver] => 0
            [minorver] => 9
            [cssversion] => 2
            [frames] => 1
            [iframes] => 1
            [tables] => 1
            [cookies] => 1
            [backgroundsounds] =>
            [vbscript] =>
            [javascript] => 1
            [javaapplets] => 1
            [activexcontrols] =>
            [cdf] =>
            [aol] =>
            [beta] => 1
            [win16] =>
            [crawler] =>
            [stripper] =>
            [wap] =>
            [netclr] =>
        )`
```

Answer (score 1):

If you can not or are not be able to install browscap.ini (needed in `get_browser`) you should use some ready-to-use class. I googled and founded this:
http://chrisschuld.com/projects/browser-php-detecting-a-users-browser-from-php/

Hopefully it helps!

Here is example using the code:

```
$user_browser = new Browser();
if($user_browser->getBrowser() == Browser::BROWSER_CHROME){
echo 'Your browser seems to be Google Chrome!';
}
```

or if you just want to print shorter version of browser,

```
$user_browser = new Browser();
print $user_browser->getBrowser();
```

And comment in the class own page even says that it´s faster than PHP´s get_browser ([link to comment here](http://chrisschuld.com/projects/browser-php-detecting-a-users-browser-from-php/#comment-3481))